# As I read this Json in php?

Tags: php, json

I am starting my knowledge of php , I have difficulty reading this array in json , I can read all the information , but I can not read data off geofences array

How can read the information contained within " geoFences " id and name ?
My json example

I need read this in php json.

```
$response =
    [
    {
    "id":441818,
    "device":{
    "id":6,
    "uniqueId":"35390906000",
    "name":"440",
    "description":"COOR",
    "timeout":3000,
    "idleSpeedThreshold":0.0,
    "iconType":{
    "OFFLINE":{
    "width":21,
    "height":25,
    "urls":[
    "/img/marker-white.png",
    "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.13.1/img/marker-green.png"
    ]
    },
    "LATEST":{
    "width":21,
    "height":25,
    "urls":[
    "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.13.1/img/marker.png",
    "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.13.1/img/marker-green.png"
    ]
    }
    }
    },
    "time":"Fri, 07 Aug 2015 23:13:06 -0300",
    "valid":true,
    "latitude":-23.1,
    "longitude":-46.1,
    "altitude":745.0,
    "speed":0.0,
    "course":0.0,
    "other":"\u003cinfo\u003e\u003cbattery\u003e58\u003c/battery\u003e\u003cip\u003e179.95.37.54\u003c/ip\u003e\u003c/info\u003e",
    "geoFences":[
    {
    "id":16,
    "name":"PL Eldorado",
    "color":"20B2AA"
    }
    ]
    }
    ]
```

I need read in php this information...

```
"id":16,
"name":"PL Eldorado".
```

Example, if i need read device->name i do it:

```
$json=json_decode($response, true);
foreach ($json as $person_name => $person) 
{   
    echo $person['device']['name'];

}
```

But i do it, don´t work.

```
   $json=json_decode($response, true);
    foreach ($json as $person_name => $person) 
    {   
        echo $person['geoFences']['id'];
        echo $person['geoFences']['name'];

    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: geoFences if i use echo $person['geoFences']['id'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have another array under geoFences.
This is the loop:

```
foreach($json as $person){
    foreach($person['geoFences'] as $g){
        echo $g['id'].'<br>';
        echo $g['name'].'<br>';
    }   
}
```